# What is the best file format for configuration file?

Tags: php

I need a good config file format. I plan on putting to table schema. Like symfony, ruby on rails, etc. What is the best file format for configuration file ? Yaml or XML or JSON encoded file ? Which is the best for this purpose ?

Comment: You do know that if you accept more questions, you get more rep, right?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As others have stated, you have loads of options. Just don't invent (i.e. write parsers)  such a thing yourself unless you have a really, really good reason to do so (can't think of any). Just evaluate your options:

- Do you need  to access this data anywhere outside my application (with another language)
- Do you want users (or yourself) to be able to edit the file using a simple text editor
- Do you need backwards compatibility with older versions of the used language

For example, PHP provides very easy serialize() and unserialize() functions. The format, however, is not as easily readable / editable by humans (XML can also be hard to read, but not as hard as the PHP format. Python's pickle module is even worse.). If you ever need to access data with other languages, this is a bad choice. And think about others - I recently hat to parse PHP serialized data from the Horde project in a python project of mine! JSON is a much better choice because its human-readable (if its "pretty-printed", not in the compacted form!), human-editable and every major language has JSON-support nowadays. However, you will lose backwards compatibility, e.g. with python, JSON requires version 2.6+.

Comment: I take issue with one part of the answer: How is XML not easily readable/editable by humans?  That's one of it's large advantages.  (It is more verbose than JSON, and nothing wrong with JSON)

Comment: Well, you're right in that it's much more readable than PHP's serialization format  or pythons pickle. But it is also extremely verbose, which I find distracting when reading and cumbersome when writing. There's a whole software category called "XML editors" for a reason ;)

Comment: I changed the answer to read "not as easily".

Comment: I find it odd that the most obvious and easy solution, as answered by @RaYell (`parse_ini_file()`), is missing from this accepted answer. Other than that the answer provides some good detail.

Comment: @ViennaMike There is some wrong with JSON, most prominently the fact that it does not allow comments. A human-editable configuration file format that does not allow comments is mostly write-only and therefore worthless.

Answer (score 17):

`*.ini` should be pretty good for that

```
[MyApp]
var1 = "foo"
var2 = "bar"

[MyPlugin]
var1 = "qwe"
```

You can easily read it using `parse_ini_file()`

```
$config = parse_ini_file('/path/to/config/file', true);
echo $config['MyApp']['var2'];
```

Comment: Great answer. Especially if long-term the language scope stays as PHP. I use .ini files all of the time as my "levers and knobs of control" in my applications.

Comment: Does ini support multiline strings?

Answer (score 5):

[JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json) is a good choice, in my opinion.  You could define your database schema as such:

```
{
    table1: {
        id: {
            type:"int",
            autoincrement:true
        },
        some_field: {
            type:"string",
        }
    },
    table2: { // etc
    }
}
```

Then just use [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to turn this into a PHP array.

e.g.

```
$tables = json_decode($json_text);
foreach ($tables as $tablename => $t) {
    foreach ($t as $fieldname => $field) {
        echo "Table {$tablename} has a record called {$fieldname}";
    }
}
```

This would print:
`Table table1 has a record called id Table table1 has a record called some_field`

JSON is much easier to work with than XML in my opinion, and json_encode/decode is very fast so there's little overhead.  In my opinion, it's also a lot more readable than XML and copes better with complex data structures than INI files.  Some people prefer YAML, but there's really not much difference in syntax.

Comment: Too bad your example isn't correct json, it's is javascript. Similar, but not the same.

Comment: And, comments are not allowed in pure JSON.. which I think is a downside of a configuration file, which might have ideas or options which you may or may not need..

Comment: Prefer [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML).

Answer (score 2):

XML is best for this purpose as most programming langauge privide API to read XML files.

Comment: XML is pain to maintain.

Comment: xml is created by the devil..

Comment: @DmytriiNagirniak  Hi, Can you explain how xml is pain to maintain? Or Please share a link/blog which explains the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What do you plan on putting in there?

You have loads of options:

- XML with custom tags
- Key-Value pairs on each new line
- SQLite?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend SQLite as a config as you will need an SQLite client tool to set up you application and you also need to be familiar with SQL queries.

Answer (score 1):

my preference is

1. well documented php file
2. database for user specific configuration

just like wordpress and countless other php applications use

Answer (score 0):

Joomla recently switched from ini files to JSON encoded files. Encoding and decoding json using `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` performs better than reading and writing ini files.

There is a drawback however: json is not easily human readable. You need to use a php script to encode your config file. You can use this solution well when you want to write your config in an administrator part of your website.

Comment: I would say JSON is pretty much human-readable (in contrast to the standard PHP serialization format).

Answer (score 0):

The guys have really given you good answers already.  Personally I like .ini files outside your document root. Also make sure (if you're on a linux hosting env) that your file is only readable by your web server and not writable.

You can then simply parse the INI file and use your configuration settings like that. (this is if you're using a language such as PHP or so, JavaScript ect won't work here.)

But it's like they said.  It all depends on what data you want to have in your config file and what you want todo with it.

Regards
Conrad c'',)