# Direction needed - how to create a customizable files?

Tags: php

Here is the flow I would like to achieve:

1. I have a set of template .php files on server.
2. Visitor of the website chooses some options
3. Options are added to template files as pieces of code
4. Visitor downloads customized files (.zip should contain both default template files if not customised, and customized ones)
5. Original files remain intact for the next visitor

The flow is similar to [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) customisation, only difference is that on bootstrap visitors are editing .less files, and my visitors would edit .php files

I would appreciate if you could point me to general direction how to execute steps 3,4 and 5, baring in mind that user input will be stored in objects and arrays with javascript.

My php knowledge is very rudimentary, so I don't know where would I start.

If you need any clarifications please do not hesitate to ask.

Thanks!

Comment: Exactly *what* files is a user customising?

Comment: @MartinBean .php files

Comment: This sounds *horrifically* insecure, especially if you’re only a novice as you say.

Comment: maybe i am not clear, the flow i am going for is the same as bootstraps customization of .less and js. files http://getbootstrap.com/customize/, except my visitor will be customizing .php files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the users only modify configuration options it seems the best way forward would be to use JSON as it is very easy to encode/decode with JS & PHP with `$.parseJSON` (jQuery) and `json_decode()` & `json_encode()` respectively.

You would provide a form and then convert these user inputs into the JSON format and store it in a `.json` file which can then be zipped up and sent as a download to your user.

This would also allow users to upload their zip files and have the form inputs defaulted to their original options.

So lets run through how bootstrap does it.

1. Page to customize the bootstrap file, you would do the same with a similar form.
2. Once the form is POSTed, take the array of form inputs and **validate** them for malicious input, correct data types such as a number etc and remove any form inputs that should not be there.
3. Convert the input into JSON, without validation this is easy as `json_encode($_POST)`.
4. Write that to a JSON file and allow the user to download it (zip it up if you want).

In your case you have multiple PHP files, this seems a bit off and you should not be using PHP files to hold this sort of variable configuration data, JSON seems a lot better suited.

Take a look at this SO question: [What is the best file format for configuration file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243345/what-is-the-best-file-format-for-configuration-file)

Three methods are mentioned, PHP's way, JSON & XML. Take your pick, but I'm willing to bet that the easiest one for you is JSON.

If you have not used JSON before, create a new PHP script and try out the functions with multi-dimensional arrays and have a play around.

[PHP Documention for JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JavaScript to store user selections etc., I recommend you don't actually use php for any of the functionality you described. So do it like this:

1. Store templates as static text file with demarcated sections to insert user options. Make the demarcated sections different from php syntax like `@@@Your option here@@@`.
2. This is easy.
3. Fetch the relevant template using AJAX and do a simple string replace in JavaScript on the demarcated sections.
4. Put the resulting php code into a `<textarea>` using JavaScript for them copy and paste into Notepad or something
5. Original files are static and code is client-side, so this is fine

Comment: thanks for the reply, but copying and pasting result won't work very well because user should be able to customize several files and download them all together with other files that are not customised in a nice .zip

Answer (score 0):

So I understand you want to ship php scripts customised for the user.

Consider having php files that cater for all possible user inputs. Then capture the user options into a configuration file where the structure is predictacable and easy to create.

For example

```
# config.inc.php
# Created by script that captures user options
$config['allow_shipping'] = true;
```

then in the php script

```
# file1.php
include config.inc.php
if ($config[$config['allow_shipping'] === true) {
  some_php_code;
}
```

Your steps will be

1. I have a set of .php scripts files on server.
2. Visitor of the website chooses some options
3. Options are sent to a server script which creates a config file.
4. Visitor downloads customized files (.zip should contain both script files and config file)
5. Original files remain intact for the next visitor (less the config file)

Some posts to guide you
[How I can create installer for website. PHP mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388513/how-i-can-create-installer-for-website-php-mysql?lq=1)
and
[PHP Installer Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115652/php-installer-script)

Comment: in this scenario, what is the purpose of config file in .zip?

Comment: @Bojana Šekeljić, the config file provide customisable runtime operation for the client.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider making default code snippets and have every "option" link to various required  snippets. That way every time an option is selected it uses the right code.
To continue with @Crafter's example, you could have the following code snippets

- `if (`
- `$config[`
- `]`
- `===`
- `) {`
- `}`

I have done this once before when I tried something similar in Java, and even though it seems to be more work than it should, it will end up quite useful once you get a sizeable "database" of code snippets.

Hope it was of any use?

-Peter